# How to update a component depending on the state of localStorage?

Tags: reactjs

I have two pages

localhost:3000 and 1.localhost:3000, after some actions I redirect and transfer some data from localhost:3000 to 1.localhost:3000, I get this data on the second page, but only after updating it, how to get this data when first redirect? To not have to refresh the second page? (The data is in localstorage)

```
// It works, but only after the update
      componentDidMount() {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
       if (localStorage.getItem('urlParams') !== null) {
       clearInterval(interval)
       const res = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('urlParams'))
       const newToken = decodeURI(res.params.token)
       localStorage.setItem('accessToken', newToken)
  }
 }, 500) 
}
```